# css middle text box

Tags: html, css

I have some text in html. About 2 paragraphs.

I want this to appear in the middle, I can do this using  in html but I want it to be "in" on the sides, so it only fills the middle of the screen, away from the edges on the sides.

How to do this?

EDIT: 
DESCRIPTION OF PAGE:

EMPTY SPACE   |<------text here------>|    EMPTY SPACE

Comment: please provide some code that you have tried, and possibly an image of what you would like to achieve.

Comment: "in" means in the middle, like the middle of the screen...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various different ways of centering text in a page. For now I will assume you mean horizontal centering.

You haven't provided any code for anyone to work with, so I will assume the code goes as follows:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse cursus sapien vitae ipsum semper sagittis porta odio tempor. Pellentesque porta mattis porta. Cras in condimentum tellus. Nam porta sapien vel felis aliquam id aliquam neque condimentum.</p>
    <p>Mauris in tellus magna. Nam cursus dapibus diam, ut cursus risus placerat sed. Praesent volutpat elementum faucibus. Donec mi arcu, faucibus eget porta a, feugiat eu dui. Sed dapibus feugiat quam, vel venenatis neque venenatis ut. Ut condimentum tellus eget ipsum aliquam eu faucibus erat egestas. Pellentesque ut metus a elit suscipit vulputate id id magna. Praesent eu sem urna, eu fermentum enim.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

To center the paragraph text in the middle of the page, you need to add the following CSS (in a `style` element or an external `.css` file): [first example](http://jsfiddle.net/QkkZS/)

```
p
{
  text-align: center;
}
```

This is probably **not** what you're after because it wont push the text away from the edges. If you would like the text to have a fluid width with some padding, use this CSS instead: [second example](http://jsfiddle.net/YJwFc/)

```
p
{
  padding: 0 100px;
}
```

You can of course center the text using both methods to make the text centered **and** stay away from the edges.

If you would like a *static* width that stays centered, use this CSS instead of the padding: [third example](http://jsfiddle.net/9LwhL/)

```
p
{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}
```

Comment: `text-align: center` centers the lines of the paragraph text within the paragraph's container, which is not necessarily the page.  I knew what you mean but David19801 may not.  I usually go with your third example but with width in `em`s

Comment: Oh, and +1 for giving the several methods and advocating for separation of styles from the elements.

Comment: @Stephen P, thanks. The `text-align: center` was more to explain that the text can be centered *inside* the container, or not.

Answer (score 0):

Think you've looking for `margin: 0 auto;` which will center your element.

So to achieve

> EMPTY SPACE |<------text
>   here------>| EMPTY SPACE

You could do

```
<div>
    <div style="margin: 0 auto; width:300px;">text here</div>
</div>
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work though. u should probably try text-align:center;

Comment: Try that now - I think you need a container element for its margin to take effect

Comment: +1, as this is the correct method. Just make sure to define a width on the element.

Comment: @m.edmondson: I don't have privileges for that.

Answer (score -2):

easiest way is to use a table

```
<table><tr>
<td style="width:15%"></td>
<td>
<------text here------>
</td>
<td style="width:15%"></td>
</tr></table>
```

Comment: I'm going to downvote this as the OP hasn't mentioned hes trying to display tabular data.  For displaying elements on the page you shouldn't be using tables.

Comment: 1995 called, they want their table-based layout back.

Comment: @jnpcl -- lmao! (anyone on my team using a table for this quickly finds themselves off my team)